# I want to make custom brand search form on home page

Tags: module, category, magento-1, search

`Dynamic display sub categories(like 7S) clicking main category(like apple)`

[image]

I am not able to start, can any one suggest something from where to start, or what should I do, to achieve this.

I know I can fetch all category and sub category, but the real task is how to `fetch sub category` `on click` of `Main category`.

Any one please suggest some step, that how this can be achieved, may be I need to use ajax, but I don't know how to do it.

**UPDATE 1**

**UPDATE 2  My module is created with the help of @MIke so posting my code so that it may help some one new in Magento as me .**

I trying to create a module for this.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\code\local\Maddy\Custombrand\controllers\AjaxController.php

```
<?php
class Maddy_Custombrand_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //echo "hello from controller";
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $parentCategoryId = $params["id"];

        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
        $subcats = $cat->getChildren();

        // Get 1 Level sub category of Parent category
        echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Model</option>';

        foreach (explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid) {
            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
            if ($_category->getIsActive()) {
                echo '<option value="'.$_category->getId().'">'.$_category->getName().'</option>';
            }
        }
    }

    public function maddyurlAction()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $parentCategoryId = $params["iD"];

        // echo "from ajax controller";
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
        $urlcat = $cat->getUrl();

        echo '<a href="'.$cat->getUrl().'"> SUBMIT</a>';
    }
}
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\code\local\Maddy\Custombrand\etc\

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
    <modules>
        <Maddy_Custombrand>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Maddy_Custombrand>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custombrand>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Maddy_Custombrand</module>
                    <frontName>custombrand</frontName>
                </args>
            </custombrand>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custombrand>
                    <file>custombrand.xml</file>
                </custombrand>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\custombrand\custombrand.php

```
 <?php
 /*
 Module Name : Maddy_Custombrand
 Author: Created By Saurabh Ranjan
 Description : This page calls controllers using ajax onchange event.
 */

?>
<?php
$parentCategoryId = 251;
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();
?>

<select class="selectBrand">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Brand</option>
<?php
foreach (explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid) {
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
    if ($_category->getIsActive()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$_category->getId().'">'.$_category->getName().'</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>


<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Model</option>
</select>


<div id="submitlink"> <a href="">SUBMIT</a></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*
jQuery(".businessTypePullDown").change(function(){
    var categoryId = this.value;
    alert( categoryId );
});
*/


jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.selectBrand').change(function() {
        var categoryId = this.value;
        //alert( categoryId );
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('custombrand/ajax/index') ?>",
            data:   "id="+ categoryId,
            success: function(html) {
                jQuery("#mySelect").html(html);
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#mySelect').html('An error occurred');
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery('#mySelect').change(function() {
        var categoryId = this.value;
        //alert( categoryId );
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('custombrand/ajax/maddyurl') ?>",
            data:   "iD="+ categoryId,
            success: function(html) {
                jQuery("#submitlink").html(html);
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#submitlink').html('An error occurred');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a controller to return the subcategories of the ID provided (i.e APPLE) and use **AJAX** to get the categories on change of the Brand Select Field and after successfull AJAX request load the returned values

Add the following script in your respective phtml inside `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#brand').change(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "path/to/controller",
            data:   "id="+ categoryId
            success: function(html){
                jQuery("#mySelect").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Update the select field ID to match your brand and brand options.

Note: Make sure you have loaded the jQuery.js in your header.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions,  let me create the module, if stuck i will ask again

Comment: where to write this `ajax` function

Comment: You have write this in your script file or in our respective phtml.

Comment: i update my post can you see once , i never worked on ajax in magento

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I am able to create the module and it's working fine